# invalid hook call usedispatch in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I keep getting this error but it's not clear why. It is a functional component and the hook is within the body. I tried searching around for an answer but it's not clear why it's having an issue.

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectItems } from "../pages/slices/cartSlice";
import { addToBasket } from "../pages/slices/cartSlice";
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart";
import axios from "axios";
```

code

```
export default function Products({ data }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});

  const pushProducts = () => {
    setItem(data.data.products.data);
  }

  

  const items = useSelector(selectItems);

  

  const addCart = () => {
    const product = {
      description,

      quantity,
      price,
    };
    //send product to basket slice
    dispatch(addToBasket(product));
    
  };
```

This is the slice
cartSlice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
items: [],
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
      addToBasket: (state, action) => {
          state.items = [...state.items, action.payload] 
      },
      removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {},

  },
});

export const {addToBasket, removeFromBasket} = cartSlice.actions

export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

Comment: Can you show us the full code for the `Products` component? Can you also show the code where `Products` is being used?